LlamaIndex Pydantic Output Parser Throwing Unbound Local Error
Trying to learn about LlamaIndex agents from this tutorial.
I am getting a response from result = agent.query(prompt). But when I try to run the following output pipeline on the result

class CodeOutput(BaseModel):  
    code: str  
  description: str  
  filename: str  
  
  
parser = PydanticOutputParser(CodeOutput)  
json_prompt_str = parser.format(code_parser_template)  
json_prompt_tmpl = PromptTemplate(json_prompt_str)  
output_pipeline = QueryPipeline(chain=[json_prompt_tmpl, llm])

# Here I am feeding the result from the agent
next_result = output_pipeline.run(response=result)

I get the following error (relevant call stack)
UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[9], line 1
----> 1 next_result = output_pipeline.run(response=result)

File ~/Python_scripts/AI-Agent-Code-Generator/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/llama_index/core/instrumentation/dispatcher.py:311, in Dispatcher.span.<locals>.wrapper(func, instance, args, kwargs)
 308             _logger.debug(f"Failed to reset active_span_id: {e}")
 310 try:
--> 311     result = func(*args,  **kwargs)
 312     if isinstance(result, asyncio.Future):
 313         # If the result is a Future, wrap it
 314         new_future = asyncio.ensure_future(result)

File ~/Python_scripts/AI-Agent-Code-Generator/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/llama_index/core/query_pipeline/query.py:413, in QueryPipeline.run(self, return_values_direct, callback_manager, batch, *args, **kwargs)
 409     query_payload = json.dumps(str(kwargs))
 410 with self.callback_manager.event(
 411     CBEventType.QUERY, payload={EventPayload.QUERY_STR: query_payload}
 412 ) as query_event:
--> 413     outputs, _ = self._run(
 414  *args,
 415  return_values_direct=return_values_direct,
 416  show_intermediates=False,
 417  batch=batch,
 418  **kwargs,
 419  )
 421     return outputs

File ~/Python_scripts/AI-Agent-Code-Generator/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/llama_index/core/instrumentation/dispatcher.py:311, in Dispatcher.span.<locals>.wrapper(func, instance, args, kwargs)
 308             _logger.debug(f"Failed to reset active_span_id: {e}")
 310 try:
--> 311     result = func(*args,  **kwargs)
 312     if isinstance(result, asyncio.Future):
 313         # If the result is a Future, wrap it
 314         new_future = asyncio.ensure_future(result)

File ~/Python_scripts/AI-Agent-Code-Generator/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/llama_index/core/query_pipeline/query.py:780, in QueryPipeline._run(self, return_values_direct, show_intermediates, batch, *args, **kwargs)
 778     return result_outputs, intermediates  # type: ignore[return-value]
 779 else:
--> 780     result_output_dicts, intermediate_dicts = self._run_multi(
 781  {root_key:  kwargs},  show_intermediates=show_intermediates
 782  )
 784     return (
 785         self._get_single_result_output(
 786             result_output_dicts, return_values_direct
 787         ),
 788         intermediate_dicts,
 789     )

File ~/Python_scripts/AI-Agent-Code-Generator/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/llama_index/core/instrumentation/dispatcher.py:311, in Dispatcher.span.<locals>.wrapper(func, instance, args, kwargs)
 308             _logger.debug(f"Failed to reset active_span_id: {e}")
 310 try:
--> 311     result = func(*args,  **kwargs)
 312     if isinstance(result, asyncio.Future):
 313         # If the result is a Future, wrap it
 314         new_future = asyncio.ensure_future(result)

File ~/Python_scripts/AI-Agent-Code-Generator/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/llama_index/core/query_pipeline/query.py:957, in QueryPipeline._run_multi(self, module_input_dict, show_intermediates)
 953     next_module_keys = self.get_next_module_keys(
 954         run_state,
 955     )
 956     if not next_module_keys:
--> 957         run_state.result_outputs[module_key] = output_dict
 958         break
 960 return run_state.result_outputs, run_state.intermediate_outputs

UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'output_dict' where it is not associated with a value

There is absolutely no variable called output_dict anywhere in my application level code. Is this variable being referred to somewhere by the library itself? Is this a library bug?
Here are my pip dependencies, if relevant.
llama-index==0.11.18 # RAG and Agent integration framework
llama-index-llms-ollama==0.3.4 # Ollama model
python-dotenv==1.0.1 # Environment variable loader
llama-index-embeddings-huggingface==0.3.1 # Embedding model from HuggingFace
pydantic==2.9.2 # Structured output processing

Any help will be appreciated.
Related, is it possible that bad/unintelligible prompt can result in a code exception?
